# How to calculate number of messages in BFT?

Tags: algorithm, blockchain, ethereum, distributed-computing

Do you know guys any mathematical equation for calculating the whole number of messages for agreement on one value in BFT (Byzantine Fault Tolerance) algorithm?

Let's say that N = 7  and  f = 2

So, how can we calculate how many messages will be sent between nodes until the agreement on one value (consensus)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the algorithm. Take a look on the PBFT paper (google it) - they have linear number of messages to agree on the operation.
Today there are a lot of BFT algorithms with different optimisations. Some of them reduces number of messages as well.
Tendermint and SBFT are good examples.

Disclaimer: I work on the SBFT algorithm implementation in VMWare.